# How to calculate euclidean distance between two stations

Tags: c#

I need to find the 2D distance between two stations. I need to create a station class that can be used to store a list of stations as objects, such as this:

```
class Station
{
    public Station(string name, double X, double Y)
    {
         Name = name;
         xcor = X;
         ycor = Y;
    }

    public string Name {get; set;}
    public double xcor {get; set;}
    public double ycor {get; set;}
}

class Program

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        public List<Station> Stationlist = new List<Station>();
        Stationlist.Add(new Station("po",1,1));
        Stationlist.Add(new Station("wsx",200,200));
    }
```

I need to create a distance method that will calculate the distance between these two stations by running it like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(Distance.euDistance(station[0], station[1]));
```

I have tried to create a method to calculate the euclidean distance but can't get it to successfully calculate the distance between the two stations. This is what I have created for my Distance method:

```
class Distance
{
  public static double distanceTEST(Station current, Station next)
  {
    return Math.Sqrt((Math.Pow((current.Station.X - next.Station.X), 2) + 
                      Math.Pow((current.Station.Y - next.Station.Y), 2) * 
                                              100000.0 / 100000.0) * 1);
  }
}
```

I want to have it print a result such as this: (that is just an example)

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}   ->   {1}   {2} meters, Name[0], Name[1], distance);
```

po   ->   wsx   56.6505106 meters

Comment: .. what is `* 100000.0 / 100000.0) * 1` supposed to do?

Comment: Oh don't mind that, I used that for some wacky rounding. I forgot to take it out.

Comment: What result do you get, as opposed to what you need?

Comment: Can you provide code that compiles along with sample data of how it's getting the wrong answer? The formula looks correct.

Comment: I believe your rounding multiplication at the end might be interfering with Order Of Operations, add a few more brackets maybe

Comment: Try this => `return Math.Sqrt(((current.X - next.X) * (current.X - next.X) + (current.Y - next.Y) * (current.Y - next.Y)));`

Comment: That's fantastic! Worked like a charm. Thanks for that.

Comment: if `current` is an instance of `Station` you shouldn't be able to access `current.Station.X` but it should be `current.X`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can write a extension method for Station class.

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var station1 = new Station("po", -7, 17);
        var station2 = new Station("wsx", -4, 6.5);

        Console.WriteLine(station1.CalculateEuDistance(station2));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
public class Station
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }

    public Station()
    {

    }
    public Station(string name, double x, double y)
    {
        Name = name;
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}

public static class StationExtensions
{
    public static double CalculateEuDistance(this Station currentStation, Station station)
    {
        return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(currentStation.Y - currentStation.X,2) + Math.Pow(station.Y - station.X,2));
    }
}
```